# Hypothesis test on periodic data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

I have a dataset of #calls/hour in a callcenter over the duration of some weeks. I need to know if the data of a specific day is significantly different from the other days. The # calls/hour follow the same trend every day (like a periodic signal) so I'm not sure of using a t-test on the average #calls/hour.